# Tab button hover state to return to up state on mouse leave of tab content

Tags: jquery, tabs

Try to make a tab button hover state to return to up state on the following conditions: -

- mouse leaves tab content.
- when the user hovers over another tab.

The code below does not attempt to perform the above functionality.

jQuery...

```
    $(".box").mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').addClass( "open" ); 

    var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
    $(".member_row .container .member-info").not($target).removeClass( "open" );
    $target.addClass( "open" );   

});

$(".member_block").mouseleave(function () {

    $(this).closest('.member_block').children('.member_row').removeClass( "open" );
    $(".member_row .container .member-info").removeClass( "open" );

});
```

HTML...

Each tab (avatar) has two divs, one is visible on load and the other hidden. The idea is to switch divs on tab hover revealing the second avatar hover state.

```
 <div id="show_ryan" class="box five columns" data-target="#member_ryan">

                        <div class="avatar">
                            <img src="img.png">
                            <h4 class="name">Name</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="avatar2">
                            <img src="img.png">
                            <h4 class="position">Position</h4>
                        </div>

 </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/273a6vss/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you hide or show the avatars adding a css class to the .box element, like on the CSS:

```
/*DEFAULT BOX STATE*/
.box .avatar-on-hidden{
    display: block;
}

.box .avatar-on-hover{
    display: none;
}


/*HOVER BOX STATE*/
.box.open .avatar-on-hidden{
    display: none;
}

.box.open .avatar-on-hover{
    display: block;
}
```

and then on the javascript you add and remove the open class to the **".box"** element.

http://jsfiddle.net/273a6vss/15/

Comment: I'm going to try implementing that but teh fiddle does exactly what i'm after, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('div').
 hover(
function() {
$( this ).addClass( "myHoverClass" );
}, function() {
$( this ).removeClass( "myHoverClass" );
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  background: blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

.myHoverClass {
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

You can use the .hover() function to add a class while hovering, then remove the class when the mouse leaves the hovered area. General example:

```
$('.elem').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('myHoverClass');
 },
 function(){
    $(this).removeClass('myHoverClass');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but although this adds and removes the class on that element it doesn't meet the two points i'm trying to achieve in the original post :)